# How do I make a wrapper component to style a picker item in react-native-picker?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, picker

I'm using react-native-community/picker v1.6.1, and I'm trying to make a pre-styled picker item to avoid having the color property on each item. Below is a showcase App.js. The red picker works as expected but the yellow one renders in black instead of yellow and I don't understand why. The code is tested in an iOS emulator with a freshly generated React Native app version 0.62.2 where I've installed the picker component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';

const YellowPickerItem = props => {
  return <Picker.Item {...props} color={'yellow'} />;
};

const App = () => {
  const [redValue, setRedValue] = useState(2);
  const [yellowValue, setYellowValue] = useState(3);

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} backgroundColor={'gray'}>
        <Picker selectedValue={redValue} onValueChange={setRedValue}>
          <Picker.Item label={'Red 1'} value={1} key={1} color={'red'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'Red 2'} value={2} key={2} color={'red'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'Red 3'} value={3} key={3} color={'red'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'Red 4'} value={4} key={4} color={'red'} />
        </Picker>
        <Picker selectedValue={yellowValue} onValueChange={setYellowValue}>
          <YellowPickerItem label={'Yellow 1'} value={1} key={1} />
          <YellowPickerItem label={'Yellow 2'} value={2} key={2} />
          <YellowPickerItem label={'Yellow 3'} value={3} key={3} />
          <YellowPickerItem label={'Yellow 4'} value={4} key={4} />
        </Picker>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The strangest thing is that the code runs just as well if I change the YellowPickerItem component to:

```
const YellowPickerItem = props => {
  return <SafeAreaView />;
};
```

It feels like I'm missing something basic about react components here, so grateful for a nudge in the right direction.
Markus

Comment: instead of the spread operator, try to use them individually, works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already tried that. This type of code works for me in other instances, it is just this particular case with Picker.Item that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **itemStyle** prop of the picker to styling your picker item.

Comment: Yes thanks, that works for other attributes but I can't see that it has a color attribute, I've tried it anyway but it doesn't change color. For some reason the color is set on each item while other attributes are set for all items using itemStyle.